# Writing cos functions with two variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I write the following function in MATLAB:

```
f(x)=cos h (x^2)
```

I have been trying this:

```
function y=f01(x,h)
y=cos(h).(x.^2);  

function y=f01(x,h)
y=cos(h)*(x.^2);7

function y=f01(x,h)
y=cos(h)(x.^2);
```

And many more instances. Nothing works. I can't find similar examples in the cos function documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the equation can be written as follows:

```
function y=f01(x,h)
y=cos(h*(x.^2));
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s not `cos(h) .* x.^2`?

Comment: Not really, what's the difference. I guess yours makes cosine of h, and then multiplies by x^2, while mine makes cosine of the full term?

Comment: Yes, it depends on how the equation is written, what you typed could be interpreted in either way, but most likely is the cosine of h.